# Store image path in db using listview and fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, file-upload

I want to store images in db having a table with column title, news, image. Can anyone help me where to place the  c# code i.e. in what handler so that it uploads in the same column for which the news  and title belong.

**Please help, will be a real great help. Please**

aspx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">

        <EditItemTemplate>
            <li style="">Id:
                <asp:Label ID="IdLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                Title:
                <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
                <br />
                News:
                <asp:TextBox ID="NewsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("News") %>' />
                <br />
                ImageUrl:
                <asp:TextBox ID="ImageUrlTextBox" runat="server"
                    Text='<%# Bind("ImageUrl") %>' />
                <br />
                Date:
                <asp:TextBox ID="DateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update"
                    Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel"
                    Text="Cancel" />
            </li>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <li style="">Title:
                <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
                <br />News:
                <asp:TextBox ID="NewsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("News") %>' />
                <br />

                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

                <br />Date:
                <asp:TextBox ID="DateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert"
                    Text="Insert" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel"
                    Text="Clear" />
            </li>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li style="">Id:
                <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                Title:
                <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                <br />
                News:
                <asp:Label ID="NewsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("News") %>' />
                <br />

                <asp:Image ID="ImageUrl" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("News") %>' />


                <br />
                Date:
                <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
                    Text="Delete" />
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </ul>
            <div style="">
                <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True"
                            ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [News] WHERE [Id] = @Id"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [News] ([Title], [News], [ImageUrl], [Date]) VALUES (@Title, @News, @ImageUrl, @Date)"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [News]"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [News] SET [Title] = @Title, [News] = @News, [ImageUrl] = @ImageUrl, [Date] = @Date WHERE [Id] = @Id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="News" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ImageUrl" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="News" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ImageUrl" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**code-behind:**

```
  protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("FileUpload1");
string virtualFolder = "~/NewsPics/";
string physicalFolder = Server.MapPath(virtualFolder);
string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(physicalFolder, fileName + extension));
string ImageUrl = virtualFolder + fileName + extension;

SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["ImageUrl"].DefaultValue = ImageUrl;

}
```

I have tried this  but with no outcome. The file is being uoloaded to the filesystem ["NewsPics"] but the path is not saved in the db.